# How to count value from the number of rows in csv and find out the last row to remove special variable

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to find out the count value from the number of the rows in csv file : this is php script ,

```
<?php
$str=null;
 if (($handle = fopen("rahul.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
            $i=0;
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    $str.= "[".$i.",".$data[1]."]," ;
                    $i++;
                }
                fclose($handle);
}
echo "$str";

?>
```

And this is csv file:

```
18-Jul-14   99.75   99.98
19-Jul-14   99.77   99.97
20-Jul-14   99.78   99.99
21-Jul-14   99.84   99.99
22-Jul-14   99.82   99.99
23-Jul-14   99.82   99.98
24-Jul-14   99.76   99.98
25-Jul-14   99.78   99.98
26-Jul-14   99.8    99.99
27-Jul-14   99.65   99.98
28-Jul-14   99.94   99.99
29-Jul-14   99.8    99.95
31-Jul-14   99.78   99.98
1-Aug-14    99.82   99.99
2-Aug-14    99.82   99.99
3-Aug-14    99.78   99.99
4-Aug-14    99.73   99.99
5-Aug-14    99.84   99.99
6-Aug-14    99.77   99.99
7-Aug-14    99.83   99.99
8-Aug-14    99.83   99.98
9-Aug-14    99.72   99.91
10-Aug-14   99.8    99.99
11-Aug-14   99.82   99.99
12-Aug-14   99.83   99.98
13-Aug-14   99.89   99.98
14-Aug-14   99.87   99.99
15-Aug-14   99.84   99.99
16-Aug-14   99.86   99.99
17-Aug-14   99.86   99.98
```

When i output this csv file i got the following output:

```
[0,99.75],[1,99.77],[2,99.78],[3,99.84],[4,99.82],[5,99.82],[6,99.76],[7,99.78],[8,99.8],[9,99.65],[10,99.94],[11,99.8],[12,99.78],[13,99.82],[14,99.82],[15,99.78],[16,99.73],[17,99.84],[18,99.77],[19,99.83],[20,99.83],[21,99.72],[22,99.8],[23,99.82],[24,99.83],[25,99.89],[26,99.87],[27,99.84],[28,99.86],[29,99.86],
```

Now I am trying to remove the comma (,) from the last value by getting to count and removing the comma for the last value.

I am trying to get the output like this:

```
[0,99.75],[1,99.77],[2,99.78],[3,99.84],[4,99.82],[5,99.82],[6,99.76],[7,99.78],[8,99.8],[9,99.65],[10,99.94],[11,99.8],[12,99.78],[13,99.82],[14,99.82],[15,99.78],[16,99.73],[17,99.84],[18,99.77],[19,99.83],[20,99.83],[21,99.72],[22,99.8],[23,99.82],[24,99.83],[25,99.89],[26,99.87],[27,99.84],[28,99.86],[29,99.86]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the last character with:

```
$str = substr($str, 0, strlen($str)-1);
```

But I would have done it a different way in the first place. Put all the strings in an array, and then join them together with `implode`.

Or, since your result looks just like JSON, you could use `json_encode`.

```
$arr = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $arr[] = array($i, $data[1]);
    $i++;
}
$str = json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can remove it by using

```
rtrim($str, ",");
```

OR

```
trim($str, ",");
```

Comment: rtrim() will remove the last value comma ?

Comment: yes sure, have you try? if not sure than try it by using hard coded value.

Answer (score 0):

First explode your result to the comma, then, implode your explode result to the comma.
The last comma should be remove.

```
$result = explode(",", $str);
$result = implode(",", $result);
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work, you have to add `$result = array_filter($result);` between explode and implode to get that behavior, otherwise it keeps empty values and reuse them.